# Use class methods inside included file in a class

Tags: php, oop

I am new to Object oriented programming.
My question is , I am including a file inside class method.
Now how can i use class methods inside required file? I used `$this->two()` and it works fine but i don't think the is the best way .If some one else is reading the code , it would be difficult for him to understand the code.
Any alternative for this?

```
//Main.php 
class Test{

    public function one(){
        ....
        require('file.php');
    }

    public function two(){
        ....
    }

    public function three(){
        ....
    }
}
?>

//file.php
<div>
    <?php $this->two(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create object from this class and call method

```
$c = new Test;
$c->two();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this file as real template

```
//Main.php 
class Test{

public function one(){
    ....
    print str_replace('{two}',$this->two(),file_get_contents('file.php'));
}

public function two(){
    ....
}

public function three(){
    ....
}
}
?>

//file.php
<div>
   {two}
</div>
```

You should read more about MVC and template engines (like `smarty`) to make more complex stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into traits:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

let say you make traitTest.php;

```
trait traitTest{
  function foo(){
    echo "foo";
  }
}
```

you can then include this beofre declaring your class and use 'use' keyword like so:

```
require_once traitTest.php; //need to be 'loaded' before you declare class

    class test{
      use traitTest;

      function bar(){
      echo 'bar';
     }
    }
```

then you can do:

```
$test=new test();
$test->foo();
$test->bar();
```

You can make many classes using one or many trait;

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you're doing is including the content of 'file.php' into 'Main.php' method one(). The end result is that on invocation of this method, the content of 'file.php' is read and a call to method two() will be made. In OOP you should avoid this kind of coupling and dependency (within different files) and you should enforce encapsulation.

Most important is to structure your code in order to avoid what your doing and if not possible, then comment the code.